# Why random seed work differently with different variation of code?

Tags: python, random-seed

The following two variation of python codes with the same purpose (generation random values from a uniform distribution) produce different values despite using the same random seed. Appreciate if anyone can explain why is it so. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1,9],[10,19],[20,29],[100,150]])
```

version 1:

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.uniform(a[:,0],a[:,1])
out->array([  5.39050803,  16.4367043 ,  25.42487038, 127.24415915])
```

version 2:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    np.random.seed(0)
    print(np.random.uniform(a[i,0],a[i,1]))
out->

5.390508031418598
14.939321535345922
24.939321535345922
127.44067519636624
```

Comment: edited question.

Comment: Place `np.random.seed(0)` outside the for-loop and it will produce the same results

Comment: Likewise, if you call each index of `a` separately, (e.g. `np.random.seed(0)` `np.random.uniform(a[1,0],a[1,1])`) it will produce the same result as that with `np.random.seed(0)` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The same seed, used with the same RNG implementation and the same sequence of random number generation calls, is guaranteed to produce the same results.

You have not performed the same sequence of random calls. First, there is no guarantee that `np.random.uniform(a[:,0],a[:,1])` will be equivalent to a sequence of individual `np.random.uniform(a[i,0],a[i,1])` calls. The implementation might happen to work that way, but there is no guarantee or promise that it will.

Second, you reset the seed before every call. You're supposed to set the seed once, up front. Setting the seed before every call in a sequence restarts the underlying random bit stream every time. The resulting statistical properties are about as terrible as the [xkcd RNG](https://xkcd.com/221/),

```c
int getRandomNumber()
{
    return 4;
}
```

The only reason this wasn't immediately apparent was because you used different bounds for each `uniform` call. Try the same bounds:

```
import numpy
 
for i in range(10):
    numpy.random.seed(0)
    print(numpy.random.uniform(0, 1))
```

and you get

```
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
0.5488135039273248
```